# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject when returning Array of String

Tags: android, c++, openssl, android-ndk

### Description of the intended goal

I'm trying to implement OpenSSL-generated public/private key pairs in Android/Kotlin using JNI, in order to implement user encryption on the information stored to the cloud server. I've compiled all OpenSSL source code and generated all .so files correcly.

### The code (C++)

The C++ code to use OpenSSL is shown below. CmakeLists.txt and NDK configuration is working fine.

```cpp
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_eu_joober_ui_entry_SplashFragment_generateRSAKeyPair(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {

    int             ret = 0;
    RSA             *r = nullptr;
    BIGNUM          *bne = nullptr;
    BIO             *bp_public = nullptr, *bp_private = nullptr;

    int             bits = 2048;
    unsigned long   e = RSA_F4;

    jstring public_key_text;
    jstring private_key_text;
    jobjectArray returnPair = env->NewObjectArray(2, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"),nullptr);

    // 1. generate rsa key
    bne = BN_new();
    ret = BN_set_word(bne,e);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_all;
    }

    r = RSA_new();
    ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(r, bits, bne, nullptr);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_all;
    }

    // 2. get public key
    bp_public = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bp_public, r);
    BIO_get_mem_data(bp_public, &public_key_text);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_all;
    }

    // 3. get private key
    bp_private = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bp_private, r, nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    BIO_get_mem_data(bp_private, &private_key_text);

    // Check public and private keys were generated correctly
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "Public key is: \n%s",public_key_text);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "Private key is: \n%s",private_key_text);

    // 4. free
    free_all:

    BIO_free_all(bp_public);
    BIO_free_all(bp_private);
    RSA_free(r);
    BN_free(bne);

    // 5. Return strings using jobjectArray
    if (ret == 1) {
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(returnPair, 0, public_key_text);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(returnPair, 1, private_key_text);
        return returnPair;
    }
    else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

### The error

If I check the Android Logcat, both public and private key seem to be generated correctly (as per `__android_log_print` output) but the app crashes with the following error when `env->SetObjectArrayElement(returnPair, 0, public_key_text);` is called:

`JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject`

The IDE (Android Studio) does not complain on any error, and the log suggests that key pair is being generated correctly, but I don't know why the keys are not being stored in the *jobjectArray* correctly. In fact, if I just simply put:

```cpp
env->SetObjectArrayElement(returnPair, 0, env->NewStringUTF("Hello"));
env->SetObjectArrayElement(returnPair, 1, env->NewStringUTF("World"));
```

the code works completely fine, my Kotlin code gets the Strings correctly (*"Hello"* and *"World"*), and the app does not crash, which makes me think that problem is only on the C++ side.

### The question

What I am doing wrong? I have checked other SO questions like [JNI converting jstring to char *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181934/jni-converting-jstring-to-char) or [jstring return in JNI program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796786/jstring-return-in-jni-program) with slight modifications and combinations with no luck.

**SIDE NOTE**: I'm using OpenSSL implementation with C++ because Android/Kotlin code does not provide the private key generated using `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance()` and `generatePair()` (only public key can be retrieved from Keystore), which I need to be stored in a different place so that user information can be retrieved even if the app is uninstalled, as every subsequent call to `generatePair()` will lead to a different key pair. If you know a different approach to this problem I am more than welcome to any suggestions you may provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never created a java string out of `public_key_text`

Try

```
char * public_key_text;
...
BIO_get_mem_data(bp_public, &public_key_text);
...
env->SetObjectArrayElement(returnPair, 0, env->NewStringUTF(public_key_text));
```

Comment: Hi @eyal-cinamon, thanks for your answer. If I follow your suggestion, then I get `Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const char *' with an lvalue of type 'jstring' (aka '_jstring *')` error. If I follow Android Studio suggestion and cast the expression to `const char*`, which then changes to `env->SetObjectArrayElement(returnPair, 0, env->NewStringUTF(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(public_key_text)));`, then the returned value is empty (""), which is not the intended outcome :(

Comment: In fact, both `public_key_text` and `private_key_text` are jstring objects, which I think that they are the C representantion of Java strings, am I correct?

Comment: You're using an not-created JSTRING OBJECT as C++ argument, and this is wrong: (1) because jstring variables were not created and (2) because "BIO_get_mem_data()" expects a C++ argument and not a Java Object. So "jstring" became "char *" (a C++ "object") when declaring variables, and in the Array you have to put JSTRING Objects

Comment: @Franbede You're supposed to change the type of `private_key_text` and `public_key_text` to `char*` instead of `jstring` (as in my example.) `NewStringUTF()` converts a C string to a java string.

Comment: Thanks @EyalCinamon and @emandt for your replies. Sorry I missed the declaration of public_key_text as `char *`, now it does not crash, but instead empty strings are returned ("") when adding public_key_text through `env->NewStringUTF()`. I can't understand why it does not return the values correctly, but `__android_log_print()` does show them in the Android Studio Logcat...

Comment: Try to put all methods that are freeing memory AFTER the methods that set Array0 and Array1....maybe those methods empty the pointer_to_char...

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thanks @emandt, now it works fine with a small modification in the keys declaration: I need to put _public_key_text_ and _private_key_text_ declarations as `const char*`, not just `char*` in order to make it work. I you put modifications as new answer I can mark it as solved, for anyone with the same problem to check this solution